# Table does not give out any output while Animate or Manipulate work

Tags: graphics, manipulate, list-manipulation

I was playing with this program and I noticed that I can use `Manipulate` or `Animate`, but `Table` gives me no output. Why is this so? Is there a fix?

```
Animate[Show[{Table[
Graphics[{GeometricTransformation[
   Text[Row[{Style["I", Large], 
      Text[Style[❤, Red, FontSize -> 14 Sin[3 θ] + 30]], 
      Style["NYC",Large]}]], {{Cos[θ], -Sin[θ]},{Sin[θ], Cos[θ]}}]}], {θ, 0, 2 Pi, k1}]}], {k1,  6.3, 0.1, 0.1}]
```

[image]

but using `Table`

```
Table[Show[{Table[
Graphics[{GeometricTransformation[
   Text[Row[{Style["I", Large], 
      Text[Style[❤, Red, FontSize -> 14 Sin[3 θ] + 30]], 
      Style["NYC", 
       Large]}]], {{Cos[θ], -Sin[θ]}, {Sin[θ], Cos[θ]}}]}], {θ,0,2Pi, k1}]}], {k1,6.3, 0.1, 0.1}]
```

[image]

Comment: `{k1, 6.3, 0.1, 0.1}` because your Table has low > high ranges. If you want to count down from 6.3 to 0.1, then use a negative step of -0.1  : `{k1, 6.3, 0.1, -0.1}`

Comment: @flinty Thankyou!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that `Animate` and `Manipulate` can correctly handle the sequencing specification you give. You can see that this is so by adding the option `Appearance -> "Labeled"` to the animation. Then you will see the current value of `k1` to the right of animation control.

```
Animate[
  Show[
    Table[
      Graphics[
        GeometricTransformation[
          Text[
             Row[
               {Style["I", Large],
                Style[❤, Red, FontSize -> 14 Sin[3 θ] + 30],
                Style["NYC", Large]}]], 
             {{Cos[θ], -Sin[θ]}, {Sin[θ], Cos[θ]}}]],
      {θ, 0, 2 Pi, k1}]],
  {k1, 6.3, 0.1, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

However, as pointed out by flinty, `Table` can not handle that specification correctly, so you should write your table like so:

```
Table[
  Table[
    Graphics[
      GeometricTransformation[
        Text[
           Row[
            {Style["I", Large],
             Style[❤, Red, FontSize -> 14 Sin[3 θ] + 30],
             Style["NYC", Large]}]],
           {{Cos[θ], -Sin[θ]}, {Sin[θ], Cos[θ]}}]],
    {θ, 0, 2 Pi, k1}],
  {k1, 6.3, 0.1, -0.1}]
```

Note that your version of the code contains a lot of unnecessary curly braces `{ }`, and calls to `Text`, which I have removed.

Comment: Thankyou!That makes it very clear.